Kubernetes API server gets unreachable
After running the 'kubelet init' command the API server becomes unreachable after a few minutes so I can't even install the Network add (Calio). I can't even inspect properly since the API server is unreachable—even 'docker ps' yields nothing in such a scenario.
The attached image is a rare case where I could get the pods status where you'd see that API server has been restarted 22 times in 14 minutes!
It's a master node configured on an EC2 instance (2 CPU 4GB RAM). Kuebelet status is active.
What can I try next?

